# ManagedBean ViewScoped for two pages

Tags: jsf

**What I want:** Use a managed bean view scoped for two different pages.

**Why:** in one page I only get a list from databe. And I don't want another managed bean for only do this thing.

**The scenario:**

**The managed bean:**

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyManagedBean implements Serializable {

    @PostConstruct
    public void inicio() {

        //used in page page1.xhtml
        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId().contains("page1")) {
            methodDoThingsPage1();
        }

        //used in page2.xhtml
        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId().contains("page2")) {
            methodDoThingsPage2();
        }
    }

    public String detail(Object object) {
        do(object);
        return "page2?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

**My page:**

*My page1.xhtml*

```
<p:column>
    <p:commandButton action="#{myManagedBean.detail(object)}">  
</p:column>
```

**What I thought:** when I click the button in `page1`, only the `methodDoThingsPage2` in the postconstruct will be fired. But, both methods, `methodDoThingsPage1` and `methodDoThingsPage2` are being fired.

What's wrong? If detail method redirect to `page2` why `methodDoThingsPage1` is fired too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, solved.

The problem was the strings "page1" and "page2" was being used in another pieces of URL.
Then i used:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId().endsWith("page1.xhtml");
```

or

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId().endsWith("page2.xhtml");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this way to initialize jsf managed bean instead of `@PostConstruct`:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{MyManagedBean.init}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Add this lines to the beginning of your jsf file and remove `@PostConstruct` annotation from your managed bean.

Comment: Is it a better practice using this?

Comment: Once I had some troubles with `@PostConstruct` in managed beans, that was a solution. I just supposed, your problem may have another solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very bad practice to do this. You should have two separate managed bean.

Just think about it.. do you really think that you should place a lot of `if` condition in the code? And you are also using the name of the views which may cause a lot of problems. What if you modifies the name of the views? You should modify your code everywhere you used it.

Answer (score 0):

I use a base class for common works in the two pages and inherit two `managedbean`s from it, in similar cases. Better than using if's.But this way you do have more than one managedbean. (and also another class)